# When to create PFInstallation

Tags: swift, parse-platform, push-notification, pfinstallation

I am new to using PFinstallations on Parse, and i am a bit confused as to how they work. I have an app that creates a new installation when a user creates an account, and i set the "User" field of the installation to the users userId so i can send them notifications easily later. I dont understand how the installation works when the user logs out or closes the app. In order to be able to always send the user a notification, must i create new installations periodically when these events (ie. logging out or closing the app) occur?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't ever need to create an instance of `PFInstallation`. The parse framework will handle that for you if you access it using `PFInstallation.currentInstallation()`. But to save it to the backend, you'll need to call one of the save methods yourself.

By default, logging out will have no impact on the installation since it is a method on the user. You can have you own logic that modifies the installation on logout to, for example, clear the user field or channels.

The parse framework writes the installation to disk on the users device. When the app stops running and then restarts, parse can just read that data from disk and have the proper `PFInstallation` object again.

Comment: Oh that makes sense. So then should i run PFInstallation.currentInstallation()  every time the user logs in, creates an account, and opens the app (assuming he is logged in and doesnt need to log in again)?

Comment: You should only need to call `PFInstallation.currentInstallation()` when you want to modify the installation. There is no point calling it otherwise.